# Can Office add-ins cache files on the local disk?

Tags: office-js

I have an Office Add-in built using mean-stack. I use [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to create folders and write files to my server.

For example, on the backend I have:

```js
router.post('/httpOnly/mkdir', function (req, res, next) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var dir = req.body.dir;
    fs.mkdir(dir, 0777, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === "EEXIST") console.log("folder exists")
            else return console.log(err)
        };
        res.json(dir);
    });
});
```

Now, I want to create folders and write files and cache images to the user's *local disk*.

For example, [custom functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview) can cache files in `<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\CustomFunctions` under Windows.

Although my Add-in is not as native as custom functions, is there somewhere in the user's disk reserved for Add-ins to cache files?

Does JavaScript API for Office has APIs to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for directly accessing the user's drive (other than cookies and LocalStorage). This is a security issue in the same way that it would be a security problem if web applications running in a browser could access the user's drive.